# Why doesn't (.*?) get everything between html tags in preg_match_all?

Tags: regex, preg-match

I can't seem to understand why I can't get all of the data between two tags after four hours, thing is 3 of them are returned but the 4th isn't (35 drops li).

```
$ string = '<ul>
    <li>
    <strong>½ cup</strong>&nbsp;white wine </li>
    <li>
    <strong>½ cup</strong>&nbsp;extra virgin olive oil</li>
    <li>
    <strong>35 drops</strong> of water
    </li>
    <li>
    <strong>½ cup</strong>&nbsp;golden flaky raspberries</li>
    </ul>
';

preg_match_all("/<li>\n<strong>(.*?)<\/strong>(.*?)<\/li>/", $string, $matched);
```

This is the result that I'm getting:

```
0   =>  array(3
        0   =>  <li>
                <strong>½ cup</strong>&nbsp;white wine vinegar</li>
        1   =>  <li>
                <strong>½ cup</strong>&nbsp;extra virgin olive oil</li>
        2   =>  <li>
                <strong>½ cup</strong>&nbsp;golden raspberries</li>
        )   
1   =>  array(3
        0   =>  ½ cup
        1   =>  ½ cup
        2   =>  ½ cup
        )
2   =>  array(3
        0   =>  &nbsp;white wine vinegar
        1   =>  &nbsp;extra virgin olive oil
        2   =>  &nbsp;golden raspberries
        )
)
```

All I'm trying to retrieve is everything inside the strong tags, and everything outside of the strong tag like it is in array 1 and 2.

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/lf8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closing tag for the 35 drops is on a new line, and your regex is missing that new line:

```
<li>\n<strong>(.*?)<\/strong>(.*?)\n?<\/li>
                                  ^^^
```

Slightly better would be using negated character class (which would match newlines if needed): `[^<]`

```
<li>\n<strong>([^<]*)<\/strong>([^<]*)<\/li>
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/gYyyIe/1)

And even better would be to use an html parser.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use regex for HTML or XML. There are other tools for that. I'm not familiar with the PHP ecosystem, but Google gave me [PHP simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). Maybe it's worth a try.

Then, if you really want to do it with regexes, then you need to make **assumptions** about your text. E.g. the attributes are within apostrophes or quotes? In what order do you expect those attributes? How many / what kind of whitespaces can you tolerate? Etc.

In your case, you made an assumption that the closing `</li>` is on the same line as the text. However, for the 3rd `<li>`, it's not true. It contains a line break. You could fix your regex by adding it:  `((.|\n)*?)<\/li>`